# AngularJS using ng-if vs ng-show

Tags: angularjs

In my AngularJS I have the following code where I check if there is a currently logged in user or not in order to switch the top app menu text from Login to Logout (login if no user is logged in) and vice versa. When I used ng-show ng-hide the app started to be extremely heavy so I tried switching to ng-if, but then the css effects on the top menu started not to work specifically in the login/ logout tab. So can someone please tell me what is the best approach to handle this situation with example please? Thanks

index.html

```
<div ng-controller="MenuController">
      <li>
          <div ng-if="userLevel() == 1">
              <a href="#/login">Login</a>
          </div>
          <div ng-if="userLevel() == 2">
               <a href="#/logout">Logout</a>
          </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
  controller('MenuController',
    function MenuController($scope, UService){

        $scope.userLevel = function(){                
            var userType = UService.checkULevel(); //This will return either 1, 2,3,4...etc
            return userType;
        };
   });
```

Comment: It sounds strange that you were getting performance issues (I assume that's what `extremely heavy` means). What's going on in `UService.checkULevel()`?

Comment: I added in my answer a different approach for the UService which can be useful.

Comment: @ivarni Nothing more than reading a $.cookie value. That's all

Comment: Then consider me confused as to why `ng-show` is a performance hit over `ng-if`. I can't understand how that happens as like the answers all point out, all `ng-show` does is to apply `display: none` while `ng-if` will go out and actually alter the DOM.

Comment: @ivarni With no-show, I noticed that almost every key stroke, every character I write in any form field the function userLevel() is called when using ng-show, so with almost every character written in any of the app form fields the app go read the cookie value. Possibly this is the reason for slow performance...not sure really but I am just explaining what happens in testing

Comment: Yeah, every scope-change will trigger the `userLevel()` function, but I would expect the same to happen with `ng-if` which is why I am confused. If you put a variable on the scope rather than a function and figure out a way to only change that variable when the cookie is updated, you'll probably see better performance.

Comment: @ivarni That sounds like a good idea indeed. I can put a variable on rootScope, access it from the controller. Thanks a lot, can you put your comments as an answer as it adds value to this question?

Comment: @ivarni Can I use $watch to watch changes to rootscope variable?

Comment: @MChan, yes it is possbile to `$watch` on `$rootScope`. I'm not sure my comments are relevant to the topic, as the question originally was about the difference between ng-show and ng-if. I just decided to dig a little deeper into the reason for asking :)

Answer (score 2):

The difference between `ng-show` and `ng-if` is that `ng-show` applies a `display: none` to the element when the specified expression is a false value, while the `ng-if` removes the node from the DOM, basically equivalent to the `.empty` in jQuery.

An approach you can consider for your element, is rather than using it within a controller, use a directive for the access level, and follow the approach described in this article, which is really flexible and allows you to have different elements in the UI depending on the user level: http://frederiknakstad.com/2013/01/21/authentication-in-single-page-applications-with-angular-js/

Another reason for your application to be slow when you check the user level, could be that every time that is evaluated your application has to perform a check on the server side, slowing the application. An approach for it would be to cache the result of that query, and then use it while the login status doesnt change. At that stage you can invalidate the cache and fetch the user level again, ready to update the UI.

Answer (score 1):

The `ng-if` directive removes the content from the page and `ng-show/ng-hide` uses the CSS display property to hide content.

I am pretty sure that no-show is lighter than ng-if and no-show should not make the app too heavy. If it is becoming heavy, I think there could be other causes for it.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `ng-if` the node is rendered only when the condition is true

In case of `ng-show ng-hide` the Nodes will be rendered but shown/hidden based on the condition if condition changes the same nodes are shown/hidden

Answer (score 1):

when ever you use `ng-if` it will render only that code which satisfy the condition.

while `ng-show ng-hide` will render the code on page but will be hidden with the help of CSS properties.

so better to use `ng-if` for reducing the line of code to be rendered on page.